# how to config lodash tree shaking in vite

Tags: lodash, tree-shaking, vite

Now, I'm using Vite2.x build my project
with 'rollup-plugin-visualizer', I found it build entire lodash package in

so, how to config the vite2.x to reduce the lodash package size
[image]

Comment: What tool did you use to visualize these files and their sizes?
Looks great

Answer (score 19):

I found this issue because I had a similar problem, maybe this helps someone in the future having a similar issue.

The easiest fix for this is to use imports like the following:

`import uniqueId from "lodash/uniqueId";`

This ensures that you add a minimal footprint to your production bundle when using lodash functions.

Another approach is to use the `lodash-es` lib which is properly tree shakeable, then you can use:

```
import { uniqueId } from "lodash-es";
```

By using the `lodash-es` lib you can safely import functions and your project won't end up with the entire lodash source in your production build.

**What's the difference?**

Why can you safely import the uniqueId from `lodash-es` but not from `lodash`?

If you compare the `uniqueId` source code you'll notice that [`lodash-es`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.21-es/uniqueId.js) uses ES modules while plain [`lodash`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.21-npm/uniqueId.js) uses CommonJS modules.

Since Vite works with EcmaScript modules I think only those are tree-shakeable (can't find anything in their documentation), CommonJS modules are harder to tree-shake in general and you usually need to do some workarounds to treeshake them.

A bit more [info on tree-shaking](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/tree-shaking).

Comment: Yet another way is to use the specific function modules, e.g. `lodash.chunk` if you want to use the `chunk` method. I did a comparison between this method and the other two mentioned, and the function module shaves off another kilobyte from the build. But to be honest i don't think that would make much of a difference, so either one of these three methods are fine. I suppose the `lodash-es` method might be the nicest because it's a simple drop-in replacement in your code.

Comment: A nicer way to use lodash-es is that, if you want to directly use _ to call lodash functions, you can import lodash-es like so: `import * as _ from 'lodash-es';` When you do this, Vite will automatically tree-shake the unused functions, meaning that it will have the same bundle size as `import {} from 'lodash-es';` without explicitly adding the used functions

Comment: @khoinguyen Thanks for this tip, saved a lot of migration work (and things like `_.get()` are easier to recognise than `get()`)